# XML "aborting build"

Tags: android, xml

in this code -

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/cb_list"
android:layout_height="50dip"
 android:layout_width="50dip"
 android:text="CheckBox" />
```

Eclipse sends me this error:

```
Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

Here is the full code (0gravity asked), even though the problem is in the "CheckBox" (at least that's what eclipse says)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/cb_list"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
     android:layout_width="50dip"
     android:text="CheckBox" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/label"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="12dip"
     android:textStyle="normal">
    </TextView>
</resources>
```

What's the problam?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that part of your code. Can you post the rest?

Comment: @SteveR How can I clean my project?

Comment: @RoniCopul : It looks to me like you are trying to create a `View` layout (for a list item perhaps?) - in that case, you shouldn't be using a `<resources> </resources>` block and should wrap your `CheckBox` and `TextView` in a `ViewGroup` such as a `LinearLayout` instead. The xml file should also be saved in `/res/layout` and not any of the other `/res` directories.

Comment: Where's the `<LinearLayout....>`?

Comment: My mistake was that I put it in the wrong folder :/ Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your error is not being triggered by Lint. In that case, Lint is probably warning you because of the Hard-coded string.

Anyway, the default severity for that checking, should be "warning", not "error".

**EDIT:**

Seeing your edit, I think your error is your root node. You're setting your elements under `<resources>`tag, it should be a layout holder, such as `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, ....

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what "Lint" is?

Comment: I use "resources" because this XML page is the structure of a list item in a list

Comment: Your item should be a layout, not a resource. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes

Comment: My mistake was that I put it in the wrong folder :/ Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code that you posted is that you need to add:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

inside the parameters on you check box like:

```
    <CheckBox 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/cb_list"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
```

Hope that helps.